# Ninject - The resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control, ninject

I get error

> The resource cannot be found.

When I try to implement Ninject in my MVC-3 application.  The problem appears to be coming from Global.asax during `CreateKernel()`

```
#region Inversion of Control

    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return Container;
    }

    static IKernel _container;
    public static IKernel Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container == null)
            {
                _container = new StandardKernel(new SiteModule());
            }
            return _container;
        }
    }

    internal class SiteModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            bool MOCKDB = true;
            //MOCKDB = false;//Stop Mocking
            if (MOCKDB)
            {
                //Set up mock bindings
                Bind<iItem>().To<LeadServiceMock>();
            }
            else
            {
                //Set up real bindings.
                Bind<iItem>().To<LeadService>();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

If I take the code above out and revert back to `System.Web.HttpApplication` then things start to work again.

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication//:System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
```

I took this code from a previous implementation that I wrote that also still works.  If I step through debug

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    return Container;
}
```

I get an error in **both** the working program and this broken one:

```
Locating source for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {b8 b2 52 86 ce 34 de 53 61 76 c9 df ff 65 8c 3f}
The file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject.web.mvc\mvc3\src\Ninject.Web.Mvc\NinjectHttpApplication.cs'.
```

I suspect I did someting wrong in `SiteModule`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `Application_Start()` with `OnApplicationStarted()`

```
    //protected void Application_Start()
    //{
    //    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    //    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    //    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //}

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```