# NinjectHttpApplication.cs not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I'm trying to make a simple "Hello World" using MVC4 and Ninject.

I'm following: [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/412383/Dependency-Injection-in-asp-net-mvc4-and-webapi-us)

I'm using MVC4 and Visual Studio 2012 Web Express and I've installed the Nuget package using the following:

```
Install-package Ninject
Install-package Ninject.MVC3
```

I've got the following global.aspx:

```
public class MvcApplication : Ninject.Web.Common.NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override Ninject.IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernal = new StandardKernel();
        kernal.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernal.Bind<IMessageService>().To<MessageService>();
        return kernal;
    }

    protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }
}
```

When I run this I find that I get an exception thrown: **Sequence contains no elements** and VS tries to open the file NinjectHttpApplication.cs for debugging.  VS can't find it though.

Any idea what's going on here?

Thanks

Dave

**UPDATE**

I've just tried the solution given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160946/ninject-mvc3-invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-no-elements), which is to move the registering bindings to the the file in App_Start, this file was NinjectWebCommon.cs in my folder, there is no NinjectMVC3.cs file there.

Comment: Looks like this question and answer may possibly be of assistance? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065938/ninject-the-resource-cannot-be-found

Comment: @Mojo I saw that one, I've just tried moving the registration to the NinjectWebCommon.cs file, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just now had the same problem.  Look into `App_Start\NinjectWebCommon.cs`  It's got the code to create the kernel and register services, and it's invoked automatically.  Change your Global.asax.cs back to the default code (with `Application_Start()` and no Ninjectery).  That got me past the error.

Comment: That was it, I had removed the binding, but not reverted the file totally.  Thanks!